# passing data between view controllers in storyboards

Tags: storyboard, viewcontroller, segue, pass-data

there are two view controllers with an embedded navigation controller. the 1st one has a table view. the second one, named "AfterTableViewController" has a label in it.

I wanna be able to set the label, in the `prepareForSegue` method which is in the 1st view controller implementation file.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   AfterTableViewController *afc = (AfterTableViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
    afc.title = @"the title"; // this works
    afc.theLabel.text = @"hello"; // this doesn't work
}
```

how should I set the label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you are only trying to set the text value of the label, it would be best to create an other NSString property for this UILabel's text in your **AfterTableViewController** and then use it when constructing *theLabel*.

Comment: this seemed to work. I created a string property in the AfterTableViewController .h file, and in the prepareForSegue, I assigned a value to it. then in the viewDidLoad method of the AfterViewController, I updated the label's text, using that string's value. I'm just confused why I can't change the label's value aside from doing this trick. maybe cuz it's 'weak' and the string property I've defined is 'strong'. any suggestion?

Comment: At the time of performSegue the IBOutlet to your UILabel is still nil as far as I know, this is why nothing is happening. I wouldn't really call it a trick though, this is a rather normal way of passing data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to add `theLabel` as a (synthesized) property within the `AfterTableViewController` for this to work.

Comment: already done that. doesn't work.
here's the project http://www.mediafire.com/?8zz3xf2qltzaszd

Comment: @MiladGhattavi is the label already defined in the storyboard or created by the controller itself? you might also want to clear up on the 'does not work' statement, how does it not work? errors, crashes, did you log anything?

Comment: it's in the storyboard and defined as a property in the 2nd view controller's code. the 'does not work' thing is just a comment. and I added it here for better understanding.
I kinda solved the problem with the answer from Wesley.
I'll post what I did in a few minutes.

Comment: @MiladGhattavi Ah, because by that time the view hasn't loaded ... doh! :)